# How to modify android application versioncode with application self?

Tags: android, version

My application could update with myself server not use the android market. So I want to change the version with the application self. Does anyone has the experience of it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible - you do not have write access to the version information of packages at run-time. You can only change it at build time.

It is possible to perform an upgrade programmatically, but the new package would have the version code specified at build-time as I mentioned above, and the device would require the "Install from unknown sources" option enabled.